# Return some values with PDO in function

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

i am using PDO to get some values of a table like : (table name is ban)

```
ID   word
1    one
2    two
3    three
4    four
```

MY function is :

```
function retBans() {
global $connect;
$result = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM ban");
$result->execute();
$a = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
  $a = $row['word'].",";
}
return $a;
}
```

and in the main php file, i wanted to get them back with this code :

```
$a = array();
$a = retBans();
$b = explode(",",$a);
print_r($b);
```

I wanted to have this :

```
Array {
[0] => one
[1] => two
[2] => three
[3] => four
}
```

But , it just return and print_r the last value (four) in array.

How can i get them like i said ?

Comment: no need for explode if you want an array, just use `$a[] = $row['word']`

Comment: @Ghost i tried it but the function return Nothing : `Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string`

Comment: It's not working with your current code because you're overwriting $a everytime in your loop, you should use `.=` instead of `=`. You'd better use Ghost' appraoch though as you're currently doing X to undo X later on, it has no sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead -

```
$a = '';
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
  $a .= $row['word'].",";
}
```

Then, you can use `explode` function

```
$a = retBans();
$b = explode(",",$a);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($b);
```

Comment: tnx, but array is empty now `Array
(
    [0] => 
)`

Comment: please update your question with the code you have changed and try to print_r($a) before explode to check if all data is present there

Comment: Fixed, with return $a in function :)